# Why are web protocols designed to have :// suffix?

Tags: http, protocols

What is the significances if `://` in a web protocol? e.g `ftp://` or `http://`

Is there a reason in the design pattern? why isn't it just `http:` or a `http.` or something like `http~`

Any reference to the documentation of this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Tim Berners-Lee it *"seemed like a good idea at the time"*:

> Sir Tim Berners-Lee, the creator of the World Wide Web, has confessed that the // in a web address were actually "unnecessary".
>
> He told the Times newspaper that he could easily have designed URLs not to have the forward slashes.
>
> "There you go, it seemed like a good idea at the time," he said.
>
> He admitted that when he devised the web, almost 20 years ago, he had no idea that the forward slashes in every web address would cause "so much hassle".

<sup>**http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/8306631.stm**</sup>

So no special reason, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

As for why they do it in web protocols, it's based on [the RFC that specifies URIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (section 3 specifying the basic syntax for a URI).  The "//" is explained directly after the basic syntax for a URI as `hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty`.  As for why they chose these symbols, I can only guess that it has to do with tradition (why is '/' the root of a unix/linux file system?) and/or familiarity with the use of the symbols.  For instance, at the top of that RFC, we see `Request for Comments: 3986` indicating that the category of the item is a request for comments, with a property of 3986.

While writing this, @fschmengler's answer seems to have confirmed this.

Answer (score 1):

As quote from [this site](http://www.zdnet.com/article/double-slash-in-web-addresses-a-bit-of-a-mistake/):

> The creator of the World Wide Web, Sir Tim Berners-Lee, has admitted
>   that the double slash we see in every website address was a mistake,
>   and that if he could go back and change things, it would be to remove
>   this oblique double punctuation.
>
> The British scientist according to the BBC News says that the double
>   forward-slash is "pretty pointless", with:
>
> "[t]yping in // has just resulted in people overusing their index
>   fingers, wasting time and using more paper". The rest of the address
>   is relatively important for the browser. Back in the "olden days" of
>   the Internet, there were http protocols, gopher protocols and ftp
>   protocols - and all followed with a colon and a double forward-slash.
>   Now we have more protocols which are used, such as Skype and AIM to
>   initiate a VoIP call or an instant message.
>
> But there is practically no reference to the double forward-slash on
>   the web, or as to why it is even there. In an interview with The Times
>   of London, he could have easily redesigned URLs not to have the double
>   forward-slashes in. Perhaps as a result, it would have reduced initial
>   frustration, confusion over web addresses and saved on paper.

So like fschmengler stated, there is no real reason...

Answer (score 0):

URLs (Uniform Resource Locators) are the standardized means of addressing pages in the Web. There are two basic types of URLs: absolute and relative. They each have their place for use in links in your Web sites.

If you want to create a custom URI scheme check out this documentation: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

As you'll see you are not bound to the double-forward-slashes. Also what about "mailto:", it seems that not ALL protocols adhere to this practice as you suggest. After reading your question I found this page, hope you like it:

http://webtips.dan.info/url.html